# select add sum below each group using select query

Tags: sql

Sample Table :

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Name])
VALUES
    ('1', 'Alpha'),
    ('2', 'Beta'),
    ('3', 'Beta'),
    ('4', 'Beta'),
    ('5', 'Charlie'),
    ('6', 'Charlie')
```

Using a select query, I want to add a row with the sum of id per name below every group. I've tried using union but I would need to do a select query per name. Names could change anytime though.

Select query result :

```
ID  Name   
1   Alpha     
1
2   Beta
3   Beta
4   Beta
9
5   Charlie
6   Charlie
11
```

Comment: As far as database management goes you've got a few issues here.  First, you'd never want to store data in a database in this manner because you're convoluding the data.  If you simply want to obtain the data, then you're better off creating a query which aggregates the data and then you manage the display in whichever view you're using.  Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry I was not able to explain it clearly . As you said I wanted it as a result of a query not while storing the data. I just included the insert as a sample table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a union having a computed column to keep track of the source name on each side of the union:

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Name AS position, Name FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(ID), Name, NULL
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Name
) t
ORDER BY
    position, ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I mean using a select query not insert in a table sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Id), Name from Table1 GROUP BY name
```

Try this to get addition of Id field and group by Name.